# which spi mode shall i use given this timing diagram

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

I need some help to ensure my understanding of how this is supposed to work.

I want to know given the attached serial timing diagram which spi mode should I use?

Based on my newly found knowledge I believe it should be mode 1
[How do you use SPI on an Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16348/how-do-you-use-spi-on-an-arduino)

Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Looks more like Mode 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see from your diagrams that the starting state of the clock line after the CS goes active is low indicating a CPOL of zero.  Also, we see that data changes after the falling edge of the clock indicating the CPHA is also zero.  This infers, according to [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Clock_polarity_and_phase), that the SPI mode is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the diagram you showed, it makes sense to use mode zero.

[image: SPI mode]

Clearly you need mode 0 or mode 1 because the clock is normally low.

Now looking at the change of the data vs the clock, it makes sense that you sample on the leading edge (mode 0) - the red lines - because the diagram shows that the data is held steady for a while after the clock changes (from low to high).

It wouldn't make sense to sample on the trailing edge because immediately after that (the blue line) the data changes.