# Sharing a Digital Pin / What to do when two components need a specific Digital Pin?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to the world of Arduino and picked up an Uno R3. I have run into a situation where I have two components that specifically need digital pin 11, 12, 13 as specified by the libraries used to interact with them.

Each component also uses other pins that were able to be specified as different with the libraries but for those 3 the libraries say I cannot change them. What do you do in a situation like this? Is it somehow possible for two components to use the same pins? Any help is appreciated.

The two libraries I am trying to use are https://github.com/nRF24/RF24 (Wifi Receiver & Transmitter using component nrf24l01+) and https://github.com/steigeia/RFID_UNID_LOGGER/blob/master/libraries/AddicoreRFID/AddicoreRFID.h (RFID Reader/Writer using component RC522).

Comment: Which hardware (components)? Which libraries?

Answer (score 1):

It seems probable that both libraries use SPI which connects to the SPI hardware on the chip via those pins. See [How do you use SPI on an Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16348/how-do-you-use-spi-on-an-arduino/)

You haven't said what libraries, nor what hardware, but you possibly may be able to share those pins between the two devices. They would both need *separate* slave select pins. Often D10 (digital pin 10) is used as a default for slave select.

Another possible solution is to use "bit-banged" SPI for one device. I have a [page on my forum](http://www.gammon.com.au/spi) about SPI which includes a bit-banged software implementation.

The library is at https://github.com/nickgammon/bitBangedSPI and is quite short.

Comment: Hey Nick first and foremost thanks for the time to help! I have added which libraries and components I am trying to use!