# Looking for SPI documentation

Tags: spi

I'm trying to use an Arduino as a slave and was searching for examples which I found many. But apart from the examples, I haven't found any documentation explaining many thing that show up in those examples.

For example, I'd like a document that would state what things like the following are:
-SPCR 
 
-SPE 
-SPDR 
-ISR 
-SPI_STC_vect

I'm asking this, because I don't and can't just copy an example and hope that it'll work, I really need to know what I'm doing.

Thank you, 
João

Comment: you know, there is a SPI library?

Comment: Yes, I do know there's a library. But is there any document available that says what are the resources of that library?

Comment: reference of he SPI library https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI

Comment: Atmega datasheet http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into the Atmega datasheet, didn't occur to me looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing SPI, a de facto standard, with the Arduino/Atmel hardware support for SPI.

SPCR, SPE and SPDR are registers of the Atmel MCU, part of the hardware support.

ISR is Interrupt Service Routine and SPI_STC_vect is the vector that point to that code. That is where the data received from the cable is read finally.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Nick Gammon's SPI explanations also. Very good, with timing explained as well.

http://www.gammon.com.au/spi

Comment: His work is amazing, unfortunately he doesn't explain what those things are, apart from ISR and SPDR. And I had no idea from where the other things came. But there are already good answers that give me somewhere to look into.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I also explain SPI right here on this site: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16348/how-do-you-use-spi-on-an-arduino/  - As for the register names, they are explained in the datasheet.

Comment: Whilst I have a personal interest in the answer, it simply isn't practical to include or even summarize a lengthy post like an explanation of how SPI works. The OP is asking for documentation and this answer is giving a link to it. In my comment above I point out that there is more documentation available **on this site** which means it is less likely to go link-dead. Another answer might be to reference the datasheet, which again would have to be link-only, unless maybe you quoted a couple of pages.