# Can Serial be safely used in an SPI interrupt routine

Tags: serial, interrupt, spi

I have anecdotal experience that using Serial.print inside a slave's SPI interrupt routine (ISR) causes issues with transmission. It also seems that interrupts may be called more than once before the main loop can react, so it is difficult to print info from all interrupts. Is this because Serial is inherently unsafe, or too slow? Can Serial be used safely inside the ISR routine?

Comment: it is not a surprise that the answer with most votes follows the dogma. but no, Serial print or write doesn't hang in interrupt.  It was fixed in 2013. https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/commit/dbe23685c27cb1467dc84140e4899a0bf8e23248

Answer (score 4):

Serial should be avoided in ISRs because interrupts are disabled inside ISRs, and Serial transmission uses interrupts to operate. Better to have the ISR set a flag that is read in the next iteration of `loop()` to print the desired info.

Comment: Hardware Serial write(byte) function in Arduino AVR core will work in interrupt. It checks if interrupts are disabled and if yes and the buffer is full, it executes directly the interrupt function, which pushes bytes from buffer to output.

Comment: @Juraj is write or print re-entrant?

Comment: it doesn't need to be re-entrant

Comment: @Juraj That is interesting to know. I was unaware of that behavior

Comment: @josecanuc, it contradicts you answer, but the question is about SPI slave where it can mess with timing or I don't know what else

Comment: Feel free to vote my answer accordingly. I did write it as it applies more generically and does not address the specific issue of slave SPI ISR. Better answers are encouraged and should be voted up!

Comment: The biggest problem I had was when the tx-buffer was full and I did an Serial.print inside an ISR. Using the highest baudrate fixed the issues I had. But I only used it for debugging, and won't really trust it for production code.

Comment: @Gerben, it was before this? https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/commit/dbe23685c27cb1467dc84140e4899a0bf8e23248

Answer (score 2):

Hardware Serial write(byte) function in Arduino AVR core will work in interrupt. It checks if interrupts are disabled and if yes and the buffer is full, it executes directly the interrupt function, which pushes bytes from buffer to output.

(All write and print functions of hardware Serial use the write(byte) function to send data.)

It depends on other factors if a long time spent in interrupt handler will disturb things.

Answer (score 1):

In general, [interrupts should run as fast as possible](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Volume1/E-Book/C12_Interrupts.htm). This is especially true when using SPI, since in the slave's ISR, the slave needs to put a byte in the SPI Data Register (SPDR) *before* the next transfer occurs. Thus it is good practice to avoid Serial transmission entirely in an interrupt, since in simple interrupts it can be by far the slowest portion of the interrupt.